# How to access top-level namespace via metaprogramming in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I can access the top-level namespace in Ruby with two colons in front of the class name, for example `::AmbiguousClass`

How could I do that via metaprogramming?

I have a lot of methods (more than 5) that validate and return a given class, all of which include a line like this:

```
player = ::Player.find_by(uuid: input.player_uuid)
```

I want to make that more general so I can just pass in the class to find by uuid and cut down all those methods into one.  This is what I've tried:

```
def validate_and_return(model_name)
  uuid_attr = "#{model_name}_uuid".to_sym
  return unless input.respond_to?(uuid_attr)
  klass = ::model_name.to_s.captialize.constantize
  instance = klass.find_by(uuid: input.send(uuid_attr))
  # validate instance
end
```

That doesn't work - it returns a syntax error:

```
Class: <SyntaxError>
Message: <"/home/dax/programming/xxx/lib/bus/converters/converter.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tCONSTANT
```

Comment: what's `input`?

Comment: input is a bound object (https://github.com/neopoly/bound/), similar behavior to openstruct

Comment: Does `klass = Object.const_get(model_name.capitalize)` work?

Comment: try with `klass = "::#{model_name.captialize}".constantize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Gorman's suggestion of String Interpolation was good, this is what ended up working:

```
klass = "::#{model_name.to_s.capitalize}".constantize
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use String Interpolation

```
"::#{model_name}".captialize.constantize
```

Comment: Michael, that wasn't exactly right, but it got me on the right track, thanks!  I'll add an answer with what worked.